# How to get data from xml by using URL

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid where I am loading the data from the data store. Bu using some url. Code is something like that.

```
 var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: SomeURL
                    }),
            remoteSort:true,
            method: 'GET',
            baseParams: {start: 0, limit: 25},
            sortInfo:{
                field: 'UPDATEDON',
                direction: 'DESC'
            },  
            reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
                totalProperty:'@Total', 
                record: 'ITEM'
                   }, [ {name:'name',type:'string', mapping:'@name',SortType:"asUCString"},
                        {name:'value', mapping:'@value'}
                     ]),
           grid:this,
           listener : {
                load:function(){
                }
           }
```

This is loading correctly. No problem in grid. I need to access grid data at some other place in my code. so for that I am call

```
   `var xyz = new MyGrid({val:1,newval:2});`
```

val and newVal are the two para for grid. But I am not getting store and store value here. Is there anyway I can get store here or get the xml value by using the same url again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your store `autoLoad: true` - if it is already binded/set with this new Grid.

Or just say `xyz.store.reload();`

> Reloads the store using the last options passed to the load method.

You can get the data form `xyz.store`. 
How to get the information from a store depends on you and what you have there stored. You can use 'find', 'findBy', 'each' and so on ([senscha doc extjs V3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store))

Comment: Actually I have no problem with `grid` and `store` and `loading`. What I want in answer is how to read the xml data from this url and access those xml values.

Comment: From your last senteces I understood something else, that's the reason for my answer. I updated my answer.

Comment: IS there any way I can get a xml data from the url. Is that simple. Can you help me in that. may be I can store in some variable or something kinda that

Comment: You said, that your store is loaded correctly. Can we see an example with the store loaded?